# Why OpenCV shows an empty window instead of an image?

Tags: python, opencv, real-time, video-processing

I'm using Python and openCV in linux. The program should read the camera and be able to change trackbars of min and max h,s and v color ranges to segment the frame in real-time. After the segmentation it should display that image in another window.
My problem is that the segmentation is displayed as an empty window.

here is part of my code:

```
while(True):

    if(not pause):
        ret, current_img = video.read()
        new_range(0)
        cv2.imshow("Video", current_img)

    key = cv2.waitKey(33)
    if key==ord(' '):
        pause = not pause
    elif key == 27:
        break
```

that is the loop for the video and the function that segments and then displays the image is:

```
def new_range(x):
if(current_img != 0):

    h_min = cv2.getTrackbarPosition("Bars", "min_hue")
    h_max = cv2.getTrackbarPosition("Bars", "max_hue")

    s_min = cv2.getTrackbarPosition("Bars", "min_saturation")
    s_max = cv2.getTrackbarPosition("Bars", "max_saturartion")

    v_min = cv2.getTrackbarPosition("Bars", "min_saturation")
    v_max = cv2.getTrackbarPosition("Bars", "max_saturartion")

    min_hsv = np.array([h_min, s_min, v_min])
    max_hsv = np.array([h_max, s_max, v_max])
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(current_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    bw = cv2.inRange(current_img, min_hsv, max_hsv)
    cv2.imshow("Segmentation", bw)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing cv2.waitKey(0) to cv2.waitKey(33) or something like that? I've noticed that the delay needs to have some value before it works correctly.

Also; what are the values that are being returned from the sliders?

Comment: I fixed it! it was something very simple current_img wasn't global so I wrote global current_img at the beginning of the function new_range(x). Thanks!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should try to avoid the usage of globals.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the image back to BGR format

```
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! it was something very simple current_img wasn't global so I wrote global current_img at the beginning of the function new_range(x). Thanks!